# Can I use PageObject::PageFactory without cucumber?

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am wondering if it's possible to use PageObject::PageFactory without cucumber. I tried it with

```
World(PageObject::PageFactory)
```

but there is no world without cucumber. I'm not able to find an example of another way.

Why would I do something that crazy? I want to create a gem that can downloaded by testers to use against a product that we test. I love cukes but I'd also like it to be used for exploratory testing. I've been successful doing this on the rest endpoints.

I know I can do this without PageFactory, but it's so easy that to use PageObject that way that feels like I'm cheating. I want to use these patterns.

```
visit(NewAccountPage)
on(NewAccountPage).create_account
```

Maybe there is another way entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. There are 2 things you need to do:

1. Include the `PageObject::PageFactory` in the object that you want to use the `visit`, `on`, etc methods. (This is what Cucumber's `World` method is doing.)
2. Define a `@browser` variable for the `Watir::Browser` object.

Here is an example of using the `PageFactory` in the main:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object'

# A page object
class GooglePage
  include PageObject

  page_url 'http://www.google.com'
end

# Including the page factory methods in the main
include PageObject::PageFactory

# Assign a browser to @browser
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

# Using the page factory
visit(GooglePage)

p on(GooglePage).current_url
#=> "https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=UxfbVdnCAaeD8QeM96CACg&gws_rd=ssl"
```